# LINQ to XML query returning wrong data

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Departments>
 <Department>
  <id>001</id>
  <Section>
    <SectionId>001001</SectionId>
    <Room>
      <RoomID>001001001</RoomID>
      <Owner>guest1</Owner>
    </Room>
    <Room>
      <RoomID>001001002</RoomID>
      <Owner>guest11</Owner>
    </Room>
  </Section>
  <Section>
    <SectionId>001002</SectionId>
    <Room>
      <RoomID>001002001</RoomID>
      <Owner>guest2</Owner>
    </Room>
 </Section>
</Department>
</Departments>
```

and this is my code using Linq to Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(inputUrl);

var sections = from el in xDoc.Descendants("Department")
                       where el.Element("id").Value.Equals("001")
                       select el.Element("Section");

var rooms = from el in sections
               where el.Element("SectionId").Value.Equals("001001")
               select el.Element("Room");

var roomsList = (from el in rooms
            select new Room
            {
                roomID = (string)el.Element("RoomID"),
                owner = (string)el.Element("Owner")
            }).ToList();
```

My problem is I only get 1 room in the List,but I should get two.Please also advice if this is the right way of using LINQ to xml,I am fairly new to LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show that there are many ways to skin a cat:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\TEST\TEST.XML");

var depts = from e in xDoc.Descendants("Department")
            where e.Element("id").Value.Equals("001")
            select e;

var sections = from e in depts.Descendants("Section")
            where e.Element("SectionId").Value.Equals("001001")
            select e;

var rooms = (from e in sections.Descendants("Room")
            select new //Room 
            {
                ID = (string)e.Element("RoomID"),
                Owner = (string)e.Element("Owner")
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `sections` and `rooms` queries to:

```
var sections = xDoc.Descendants("Department")
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("id") == "001")
                   .Elements("Section");

var rooms = sections.Where(x => (string)x.Element("SectionId") == "001001")
                    .Elements("Room");
```

With these, you'll get 2 rooms.

Why isn't your code working?

1. `select el.Element("Section")` selects only first `section` element within `Department` - you'd never be able to get room from `section` with `id == "001002"`
2. `select el.Element("Room")` in `rooms` query returns only first room from every matched section.

You can change `Element` to `Elements` and add additional `SelectMany(x => x)` calls to make your syntax-based queries work:

```
var sections = from el in xDoc.Descendants("Department")
                where el.Element("id").Value.Equals("001")
                select el.Elements("Section");

var rooms = from el in sections.SelectMany(x => x)
            where el.Element("SectionId").Value.Equals("001001")
            select el.Elements("Room");

var roomsList = (from el in rooms.SelectMany(x => x)
                    select new 
                    {
                        roomID = (string)el.Element("RoomID"),
                        owner = (string)el.Element("Owner")
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why this code worked - i.e., what's different about it?

Comment: Yes, it is - thanks! I was scratching my head trying to figure out an answer for this one.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could use the [Extensions.XPathSelectElements Method (XNode, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) (make sure you add the `using System.Xml.XPath` directive to the top of your file):

```
string 
    departmentId = "001", 
    sectionId = "001001";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(inputUrl);
var rooms = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
    String.Format(
        "//Department[id={0}]/Section[SectionId={1}]/Room",
        departmentId,
        sectionId))
    .Select(el => new Room
    {
        roomID = (string)el.Element("RoomID"),
        owner = (string)el.Element("Owner")
    }).ToList();
```

It's a matter of own preference. I find this shorter to write and easier to read.

Comment: I think this is my preferred solution; it is fairly easy to read.

Comment: I love this ,pretty neat:-)

Comment: Sorry I changed my mind to use Linq to Xml,This small example was a makeover to ask a problem,my xml files are quite large and as per this I see point for using Linq to Xml than XPath http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/12/04/LINQ-to-XML-and-LINQ-to-XML-with-XPath-performance-review.aspx

Comment: No problem and nice link!

Answer (score 0):

What if you change:

```
select el.Element("Room");
```

to

```
select el.Elements("Room");
```

Comment: If I use Elements("Room") I get this error Error System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) at this Line                                        roomID = (string)el.Element("RoomID"),

Comment: That's not the only problem here. He's also taking only first `section` from `Department`.

Answer (score 0):

You're only selecting one room in the middle query, it should be `.Elements(...)` (pay attention to the trailing `s`):

```
        var rooms = from el in sections
                       where el.Element("SectionId").Value.Equals("001001")
                       select el.Elements("Room");
```

The same applies to your `section` query.

Comment: If I use Elements("Room") I get this error Error System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) at this Line roomID = (string)el.Element("RoomID"),

Comment: That's not the only problem here. He's also taking only first `section` from `Department`.