# Reading alphanumeric values from xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

As per my last question
[LINQ to XML query returning wrong data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268870/linq-to-xml-query-returning-wrong-data)

I am reading this XML in following way using XPath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Departments>
  <Department>
    <id>001</id>
    <Section>
      <SectionId>001001</SectionId>
      <Room>
        <RoomID>001001001</RoomID>
        <Owner>guest1</Owner>
      </Room>
      <Room>
        <RoomID>001001002</RoomID>
        <Owner>guest11</Owner>
      </Room>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <SectionId>001002</SectionId>
      <Room>
        <RoomID>001002001</RoomID>
        <Owner>guest2</Owner>
      </Room>
    </Section>
  </Department>
</Departments>
```

reading code is

```
 string  departmentId = "001", sectionId = "001001";
 var xDoc = XDocument.Load(inputUrl);
 var rooms = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(
 String.Format(
    "//Department[id={0}]/Section[SectionId={1}]/Room",
    departmentId,
    sectionId))
.Select(el => new Room
 {
    roomID = (string)el.Element("RoomID"),
    owner = (string)el.Element("Owner")
}).ToList();
```

But when I change the sectionId to string "str1234" in xml and code ,It returns zero rooms.I checked so many times,Is there a problem using alphanumeric values for elements?

Comment: Is there actually any `SectionId = str1234` in your sample xml?

Comment: OP indicated that he changed in both the XML and his code.  I've been able to reproduce the issue as well - not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding the `{1}` with apostrophes:

```
String.Format(
    "//Department[id={0}]/Section[SectionId='{1}']/Room",
    departmentId,
    sectionId))
```

Comment: Thanks Grant,It works:-),I tested with alphabet only string also.It seems for all strings we should use apostrophes and for numeric only values it just works fine.